# How can I calculate the likelihood of my data given that two variables in my data are dependent?

Tags: independence, likelihood, conditional-independence

I have a data set D that has 3 variables X, Y, Z, where each variable has 100 samples and have a Normal distribution. I am interested in calculating $p(X \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp Y | D)$ and $p((X \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp Y| Z) | D)$ using Bayes rule:

$p(X \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp Y | D) = \frac{p(D | X \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp 
 Y)p(X \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp Y)} {p(D)}$

$p((X \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp Y | Z) | D) = \frac{p(D | (X \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp Y | Z))p(X \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp Y | Z)}{p(D)}$

I don't know how to calculate $p(D | X \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp Y)$ and $p(D | (X \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp Y | Z))$. Does anybody know how to do that mathematically?

Comment: Could you explain what your operator "$\not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp$" means? From the context it must be some way of indicating an event, but exactly what event in terms of $X$ and $Y$ would it be?

Comment: It mean dependence (not independent). You can read the first term as the probability that X is dependent on Y given data set D, and you can read the second term as the probability that X is dependent on Y conditional on Z given data set D.

Comment: For that to make sense, we would need to posit a model in which the *bivariate distribution* of $(X,Y)$ (not $X$ and $Y$ themselves!) would depend on $D.$  I think you need to make this explicit and clear.

Comment: Each variable has a Normal distribution, therefore, their joint density has a multivariate normal distribution.